# How can I make the widths of other cells to be a percentage of the remaining width?

Tags: html, css

With a table that has automatic margins and cells that have a predetermined width, how can I make the widths of other cells to be a percentage of the remaining width?

[image]

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
}

section {
  background: white;
  width: calc(50% - 60px);
  display: inline;
}

section:first-child {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>cell 1</section>
  <section>cell 2</section>
  <section>cell 3</section>
</div>
```

[inspired by a question from KaizenCyrus](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/onxu9i/with_a_table_that_has_automatic_margins_and_cells/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect job for `grid`. Use `display: grid;` and `grid-template-column: 60px 1fr 1fr;` (1fr means that the column of the 2th and 3th has 1 fraction of the remaining size of the table).

Bonus: use grid gap to handle the margin between elements.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
}

section {
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>cell 1</section>
  <section>cell 2</section>
  <section>cell 3</section>
</div>
```

[inspired by an answer from Routine_Potential_59](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/onxu9i/with_a_table_that_has_automatic_margins_and_cells/h5v0yi8/)

Comment: good code so far but you could optimize your hacky border simulation. To simulate a border-collapse within a grid you can use `box-shadow`: remove the `background-color` from both the parents and the cards. and add `section { box-shadow:0 0 0 10px purple; }`

Comment: Well this is not false but a bit out of scope.